# jetty close the connection with idle timeout 30s instead of configured timeout(60s)

Tags: jetty, rest

I am using spring boot for Rest API services.
We see lots of idle timeout problems when reading data. It reported "java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException: Idle timeout expired: 30000/30000 ms " Below is what I configured for the jetty thread pool. Anyone knows why it was failed with timeout 30s not 60s?

int threadPoolIdleTimeout = 60000;
ThreadPool threadpool = new QueuedThreadPool(maxThreads, maxThreads, threadPoolIdleTimeout,
new ArrayBlockingQueue(threadPoolQueueSize));

Answer (score 1):

Unrelated.

That's the thread idle timeout, for reducing the number of idle threads in the thread pool.

The connection idle timeout is a different configuration.

Check the ServerConnector if a normal server connection.

Check the AsyncContext idle timeout if you are using Servlet Async Processing, or Servlet Async I/O.

Check the WebSocket Session if you are doing WebSocket requests.

Check the database DataSource configuration if you are worried about database connection idle timeouts.

Check the HTTP2 Session configuration for dealing with the virtual connections on an HTTP/2 connector.

And many more, etc ...

There's lots of idle timeouts, specific for the situation you are dealing with, be aware of them.